# Modify t4 template to generate write text in two files

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, t4

I have MyModel.tt for my entity model (MyModel). I need to modify my MyModel.tt file. What I want is that my simpleProperties write in one class while navigationProperties and complexProperties in other class. I have find the lines but now completely blank what to do.

Here is the code where (I think) I have to write code which will write properties in different classes.

```
<#
    }
    var simpleProperties = typeMapper.GetSimpleProperties(entity);
    if (simpleProperties.Any())
    {
        foreach (var edmProperty in simpleProperties)
        {
#>
    // TODO: Write this in entityName.cs
    <#=codeStringGenerator.Property(edmProperty)#>
<#
        }
    }
    if (complexProperties.Any())
    {
#>
<#
        foreach(var complexProperty in complexProperties)
        {
#>
    // TODO: Write this in entityNameComplex.cs
    <#=codeStringGenerator.Property(complexProperty)#>
<#
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are asking how to write the your "codeStringGenerator" stub or just to separate the output into two files.  If you are just looking to separate the output into two files, then the little snippet below should work.

```
<#
        relativeOutputFilePath = @"\Output\" + oneTable.Name + "_List.aspx";
        TemplateHelper.WriteTemplateOutputToFile(relativeOutputFilePath, Host, GenerationEnvironment);
        GenerationEnvironment = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
#>
```

Essentially all this does is grab the string that has been built by your template so far, writes it to a file of your choosing, and then resets the string for the next template.

This was taken from this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223421/t4-template-to-create-multiple-html-for-example-output-files-per-table-from) which may provide more information.